# Why is the symbol for $\arcsin(\theta)$ also $\sin^{-1}(\theta)$ if $\sin^2(\theta)=(\sin(\theta))^2$?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

Why is the symbol for $\arcsin(\theta)$ also $\sin^{-1}(\theta)$ if $\sin^2(\theta)=(\sin(\theta))^2$? I understand what they represent but I am curious why are the symbols like this?

Comment: Because the "inverse" function is not the reciprocal. $\dfrac {\sin \theta}{\sin \theta}=1$ while $\sin^{-1}(\sin (\theta))=\theta$.

Comment: It's just convenience, especially when writing by hand, to have a shorter way of writing things. Yes, it's not completely consistent to have notational conventions like this, but the context makes it clear what is meant. If it bothers you, use arcsin and write the reciprocal as a fraction or with outer parentheses (I have often done that in introductory courses to avoid confusion).

Comment: I think this comes from the hand held computers industry: it's very hard to fit  `arcsin` on a key width. As the standard notation for the inverse of the function $f$  is $f^{-1}$, they found this one to replace `\arcsin`.

Comment: @Bernard, this is just not so. I pre-date hand-held computers (well not the abacus ..) and always wrote $\sin^{-1}$ at school, $\arcsin$ didn't make an appearance until we learned about proper function notation.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: unless I am wrong, the functional inverse of the sine was always *called* the arc sine, and I acknowledge that the notations $\arcsin$, $\text{asin}$ and $\sin^{-1}$ coexist.

Comment: I guess the short answer is: is just a poor just choice, but since everybody uses it, you'd better get used to it!

Comment: @YvesDaoust, this must be a cultural thing. In 1950s Scotland I never heard the words "arc sine" until I was well into my university course, everyone said "sin t' th' minus one".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer I give to (fairly strong) students in my calculus tutorials when they ask about this. I usually offer a handout with this explanation to anyone who is frustrated by this clash in notation.

The operation of multiplying nonzero real numbers has a couple of important properties that are relevant here:

- for any real numbers $a,b$, the number $a \cdot b$ is still a real number (this doesn't require that they be nonzero)
- $a \cdot 1 = a$ for all real $a$ (doesn't require nonzero either)
- for all nonzero $a$, there is a number $b = 1/a$ such that $ab = 1$

(The algebraic term for a collection of numbers or operations with properties like this is a *group*.)  Since $a^{m+n} = a^m a^n$ for positive integers $m,n$, the third property gives us the idea to define $a^0 = 1$, which makes it natural to define $a^{-1} = 1/a$.

When it comes to invertible functions on the real line, there are *two* different operations that satisfy these properties: pointwise multiplication, i.e $f \cdot g$ defined by $(f \cdot g)(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$; and composition, i.e. $f \circ g$ defined by $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$. For composition, the "$1$" is actually the *identity* function, $\mathrm{id}(x) = x$. We have to be careful about dividing by zero and making sure that domains and ranges line up nicely and everything, but morally this is what is happening.

Since both operations (pointwise multiplication and composition) mostly satisfy the group properties that motivate our use of exponent notation for real numbers, it's only natural to put exponents on functions, too. But there's an ambiguity: $f^3$, for instance, could mean
$$
f^3(x) = f(x) \cdot f(x) \cdot f(x)
$$
or 
$$
f^3(x) = f(f(f(x)))
$$
This ambiguity extends to negative exponents, too. So $g = f^{-1}$ could refer to either of two functions:

- the *reciprocal* or *multiplicative inverse* of $f$, i.e. the function $g$ such that $f(x) \cdot g(x) = 1$ for all $1$ (whenever $f(x) \neq 0$)
- the *(compositional) inverse* of $f$, i.e. the function $g$ such that $f \circ g = g \circ f = \mathrm{id}$, i.e. $f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = x$ (whenever $x$ is in both the domain and the range of $f$)

In most situations, it's clear from context which one of these is intended, but when you're learning, it can be tough to interpret the context. The situation is particularly unfortunate for the basic trig functions, because they come in before students have had a lot of experience reasoning about functions more systematically.

Answer (score 0):

Too many parenthesis are annoying, and this explains why $(\sin(x))^2$ is usually written $\sin^2(x)$. In the same contexts, the *multiplicative* inverse will often be written as a fraction $\dfrac1{\sin(x)}$, or using the corresponding function $\csc(x)$. And the negative powers give $\dfrac1{\sin^2(x)}$ or $\csc^2(x)$.

Unfortunately, for the *functional* inverse we only have the exponent notation and write $f^{-1}(x)$ for general functions. This comes from the notation for function iteration $f^2(x):=f(f(x))$, which enforces an additive composition law $f^n(f^m(x))=f^{n+m}(x)$. So it is coherent that $f(f^{-1}(x))=f^1(f^{-1}(x))=f^{1-1}(x)=f^0(x)=x$.

In practice, $\sin^n(x)$ will "by default" denote a power of the sine for any $n\ne-1$, because iteration of the sine is exceptional (and iteration of the inverse virtually never used). On the opposite, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is ambiguous and one should prefer $\arcsin(x)$ or $\csc(x)$. If you ever use $^{-1}$, make sure that the meaning is obvious from context, or announce it.